# Mapping User Properties Fails

Tags: user-profile-service

I have the User Profile Service set up to map Active Directory users to Sharepoint.  Its all working, but I'm having trouble when trying to make the mobile field import into the CellPhone field in Sharepoint.

In CA, I go to Manage Service Applications > User Profiles Service > Manage User Properties and edit the mobile field.  Under add a new mapping, I set it to import from Active Directory mobile field, but when I click OK I get "An error occurred when updating a property".

In Event Viewer I get several errors:

- Microsoft.ResourceManagement: System.Data.DataException: This request has an invalid target: 21FCA237-910C-4245-82A5-1B9A1ADE4B89. The invalid target identifier is 5DCB74B6-90DE-4987-84C1-2EA968F5E35A.
- System.Data.DataException: This request has an invalid target: 21FCA237-910C-4245-82A5-1B9A1ADE4B89. The invalid target identifier is 5DCB74B6-90DE-4987-84C1-2EA968F5E35A.
- Microsoft.ResourceManagement: System.Data.ConstraintException: Schema validation failed.
- Microsoft.ResourceManagement.Service: System.ServiceModel.FaultException: Access to the requested resource(s) is denied

I have tried:

- Stopping / starting the User Profile & Syncronization services
- Restarting the server
- Creating a new property and mapping to that instead (same error)
- Setting the farm account as a local admin

Anyone have any ideas?!  I'm completely at a loss here...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just having to delete the User Profile Service and recreate it - once I did this all worked absolutely fine.

I figure the problem must have been introduced during one of the SP or CU applied?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have any special permissions defined in AD regarding the account you're using. Also double check that the Replicate Directory Permissions is set correctly for the account ([here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh296982.aspx)).